# Как правильно построить url при создании сервиса?

Tags: java, любой-язык, rest

Прочитал пару статей по созданию `Rest` сервисов и появилось несколько вопросов.

***Допустим у меня есть такие вот сущности:***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для `CRUD` операций с сущностью `organization` я использую `POST`, `GET`, `PUT` и `DELETE` методы по по такому `url`: `/organizations/`.

***Вопрос:***

Допустим я хочу посмотреть всех участников какого-нибудь мероприятия. Такой `URL` будет достаточно большим: `/organizations/{organizationId}/actions/{actionId}/members`.

А если у участников появятся еще какие-то сущности, то путь путь может разростить до совсем огромных размеров. Так и задуманно или я что-то не так понял ?

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря не вижу ничего криминального в такой ссылке. 
Если Вам не нравится длина, то попробуйте сократить `organizations -> org`.

При такой организации API другому разработчику будет сразу понятна структура и ему легче будет войти в проект. Особенно если это разработчик клиенткской части.

Если у вас имеется слишком много действий, я бы предложил отойти от концепции "прохода" через организацию и сделать примерно так:

```
  /actions/{actionId}/members?organizationId={someId}
  /actions/{actionId}/done?organizationId={someId}
  /actions/{actionId}/scheduled?organizationId={someId}
```

Т.е. перенести организацию в параметр запроса.